# How do I solve bug in my flutter project?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am a beginner in flutter and my app give bug after building it.

My project is an handyman project and I keep having issue with pubspec.yaml. I need help on how to resolve this to avoid getting bugs in my app.

Comment: add your pubspec.yaml here so that user can check the issue.

Comment: Please provide informations about your problem. 
Erro message, pubspec.yaml content, etc.

Comment: Thank for your replys. Below is the code when I try to build the apk file.

Comment: This code below is part of my androidManifest.xml file. But application name, android icon, android name and android theme have all be red highlighted. 
        android:label="SafeFix Vendor"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"

Comment: Also got this when trying to build which give error each time... M:\Handyman\App_source_code_v2\Freelancer_app\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:15:9-22:20 Error:
 android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <receiver#com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.

Comment: Continuation of errors I got.... FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseMainManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <receiver#com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.